# Oracle outer join and constant values

Tags: oracle, join

(I posted similar question on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555802/oracle-outer-join-and-constant-values) but moving it here as there was a downvote. This is follow-up of the original question)

I've multiple outer joins on constants as below in the SQL:

```
select .. 
from CLAS MDP, CLAS ORG_CNTRY, CLAS BEN_CNTRY, TRAN TXN 
where 
    ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
    AND   ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
    AND   BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID(+) = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
    AND   BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT     = MDP.CB_DT
    AND   TXN.SEND_CTRY_CD  = ORG_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD(+)
    AND   TXN.RCIP_CTRY_CD  = BEN_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD(+)
```

Is the above query equivalent to the below? Please advise.

```
SELECT … 

FROM 
    CLAS MDP 

    left join CLAS ORG_CNTRY on 
    ORG_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT AND ORG_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'

    left join CLAS BEN_CNTRY 
    on BEN_CNTRY.CB_DT = MDP.CB_DT AND BEN_CNTRY.LAS_ID = 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'

    RIGHT JOIN TXN 
    ON TXN.RCIP_CTRY_CD  = BEN_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD

    LEFT JOIN CLAS ORG_CNTRY 
    ON TXN.SEND_CTRY_CD  = ORG_CNTRY.CLAS_SCHM_CD
```

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to answer your question if I didn't have to format your code into a readable state for you.

Comment: @Jacobm001. Formatted to an extent. Please check now.

Comment: @Jacobm001 thnx for the formatting. You misplaced some `(+)` while doing that but it's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not the same. Though I think they're equivalent to what your original query wanted. In an oracle database `(+)=` is an acceptable (if less ideal) way to write a left join. Likewise, `=(+)` denotes a right join.

Your original join contains the set:

```
org_cntry.las_id     (+)= 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
and org_cntry.cb_dt     = mdp.cb_dt
and ben_cntry.las_id (+)= 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
and ben_cntry.cb_dt     = mdp.cb_dt
```

This block mixes left and inner join notation. When you mix any form of an outer join and an inner join, it becomes an inner join. If you change the block to

```
org_cntry.las_id     (+)= 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
and org_cntry.cb_dt  (+)= mdp.cb_dt
and ben_cntry.las_id (+)= 'COUNTRY_LOOKUP'
and ben_cntry.cb_dt  (+)= mdp.cb_dt
```

that'll fix that problem.